# Deleting row if duplicate after a replace statement

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I need to be able to remove spaces that are inside an email, I have already done TRIM so I only need to remove spaces inside the actual string.
I found this code to do this

```
SELECT email,TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(email,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''))
```

The problem is that the email is a primary key and when i run this query it errors.
Error Code: 1062
So I need to be able to delete the row that I updated IF it is then a duplicate entry.

I will keep researching for an answer now but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the idea below help.

1. Create a new empty table with same structure with the original

> CREATE table TEMP_TABLE like YOUR_ORIGINAL_TABLE

2. Using insert ignore to insert all record from YOUR_ORIGINAL_TABLE with new email to TEMP_TABLE so that duplicated email will be ignore.

> INSERT IGNORE into TEMP_TABLE SELECT ID, FIELD_1, FIELD_2, TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(email,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r','')), FIELD_N FROM YOUR_ORIGINAL_TABLE

3. Backup YOUR_ORIGINAL_TABLE and then rename TEMP_TABLE to YOUR_ORIGINAL_TABLE

Comment: I don't think i will be able to do this as it is the companies and the table that i would be copying contains 6.9 mil records so the copying would take along time and slow down the server which would be bad because there are other departments doing pulls and counts from this table. I'm not sure if this changes anything but the emails i am editing/updating are also in this database but they are marked with a 4 in a certain column to make them different from the rest. Would that change anything about this idea?